# Testcafe - Test command line argument outside test case

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

As I'm getting familiar with Testcafe, I'm trying to use a command line argument to give the user more information on how to run tests. For that reason, I'm using the `minimist` package.

However, I cannot print or use any variables outside the test cases. Please find below my code.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import minimist from 'minimist';

const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
const env = args.env;

console.log('*** A SAMPLE CONSOLE OUTPUT ***'); // does not print

fixture `Getting Started`
  .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test('My first test', async t => {
  console.log('*** ANOTHER SAMPLE CONSOLE OUTPUT ***'); // prints
  await t
    .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
    .wait(1000)
    .click('#submit-button')

    // Use the assertion to check if the actual header text is equal to the expected one
    .expect(Selector('#article-header').innerText).eql('Thank you, John Smith!');
});
```

I want to write an if statement that checks if `env === ''` or use a default argument.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I cannot print or use any variables outside the test cases.

Please use a programming way to run TestCafe.
I've changed you code example (`test.js`) and created a file that runs TestCafe programmatically (`run.js`).
Put these files into a folder and perform command `'node run.js --env value'` in your terminal.
Then you will see the following output:

```
'*** A SAMPLE CONSOLE OUTPUT ***'
Getting Started
value
```

```js
test.js

import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import minimist from 'minimist';

const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
const env = args.env;

console.log('*** A SAMPLE CONSOLE OUTPUT ***'); 

fixture `Getting Started`
  .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test('My first test', async t => {
  console.log(env); // prints
  await t
    .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
    .wait(1000)
    .click('#submit-button')
    .expect(Selector('#article-header').innerText).eql('Thank you, John Smith!');
});
```

```js
run.js
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let runner           = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338, void 0, true)
    .then(testcafe => {
        runner = testcafe.createRunner();
    })
    .then(() => {
         return runner
            .src('test.js')
            .browsers('chrome')
            .run()
            .then(failedCount => {
                console.log(`Finished. Count failed tests:${failedCount}`);
                process.exit(failedCount)
            });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution to accomplish this is:

1) Create a separate `config.js` file that will handle your custom command-line options:

```
import * as minimist from 'minimist';

const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));

// get the options --env=xxx --user=yyy from the command line
export const config = {
  env: args.env,
  user: args.user,
};
```

2) In you test file:

remove any code outside the `fixture` and the `test` methods.

import the config file and inject it in the TestController context

get the command args via the TestController context

```
import 'testcafe';
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import { config } from './config';

fixture('Getting Started')
  .beforeEach(async (t) => {
    // inject config in the test context
    t.ctx.currentConfig = config;
  });

test('My first test', async (t) => {
  // retrieve cli args from the test context
  const currentConfig = t.ctx.currentConfig;
  console.log(`env=${currentConfig.env}`);
});
```

Comment: but what if the user calls the test script without any parameters? (or with a wrong/non-existing one)

Comment: @William, the `config.env` will be simply undefined.