# TestCafe Runner - Is it possible to pass a constant from the createRunner file to tests

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, test-runner

I need to pass a url to all tests executed in a createRunner.  I have used args to do this executing tests from command line.  Is there a way to pass a constant from the createRunner to tests executed?  See createRunner below I am using.  Thanks.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

let testcafe = null;
let runner = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe     = tc;
        runner = testcafe.createRunner();

    return runner
        // list multiple test files
        .src([
            'tests/login.js'
        ])
        .browsers(['chrome'])
        .concurrency(2)
        .reporter('slack')
        .run({
            skipJsErrors: true,
            quarantineMode: true,
            selectorTimeout: 30000,
            assertionTimeout: 10000,
            pageLoadTimeout: 15000,
            speed: 0.9
        });
})
.then(failedCount => {
    stream.end();
    console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
    testcafe.close();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to programmatically inject command-line args. Before returning the runner, insert these lines:

```
process.argv.push('--foo=bar');
process.argv.push('--yo');
```

In the test files use `minimist` to get your custom cli args.

Your question is also [related to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697349/testcafe-test-command-line-argument-outside-test-case)

Comment: Thanks!  Works great.